# WPF XamlParseException is not bubbled up to main exception handler

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm subscribing to the following unhandled ex event's in my WPF app.
And I can mostly be sure that all the exceptions will be handled by the 'HandleException' function

```
public void SetupExceptionHandling(Action<Exception> logErrorAction = null)
{
    this._app.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += (DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler) ((s, args) =>
    {
        args.Handled = true;
        this.HandleException(args.Exception, logErrorAction, false);
    });

    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (EventHandler<UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs>) ((s, args) =>
    {
        args.SetObserved();
        this.HandleException((Exception) args.Exception, logErrorAction, false);
    });
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (UnhandledExceptionEventHandler) ((s, args) => this.HandleException(args.ExceptionObject as Exception, logErrorAction, args.IsTerminating));
}
```

My problem is - that when Presentation Framework encounters an exception (while it's trying to create a view, and assigning a ViewModel to it - the ViewModel Constructor throws an Exception.

this is what I see in VS - but the exeptions is not bubbled up :(
[image]

I would expect that exception to by bubbled up - to the main exception event handler but for some reason it goes to Dev->null

Does anyone have ideas why ?

Adding a StackTrace

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `SetupExceptionHandling` is executed? Also provide the stack trace of the `XamlParseException` exception.

Comment: The stack Trace - fails in the ViewModel constructor, which causes the presentation framework to throw XamlParseException. And Yes - I tested that setupExHandling is executed

Comment: No, it isn't a stack trace. It's a target site. And I was asking about `XamlParseException`'s stack trace. It should contain the name of the method which catches the `XamlParseException` exception. If it's a secret then enable source stepping and debug by yourself.

Comment: added the details.. but not much is in there

Comment: Hm... There's not enough info to answer you. So I think that the better way in your case is to enable .Net Framework Source Stepping in Debugging Options and to try find who eats `XamlParseException`.